# What does “get rolled” in “Eight ways Trump got rolled in his first budget negotiation” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

[The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/paloma/daily-202/2017/05/01/daily-202-eight-ways-trump-got-rolled-in-his-first-budget-negotiation/590687f2e9b69b3a72331f09/?utm_term=.1099ce2a3ab4) (May 1st) runs an article under the headline, “Eight ways Trump got rolled in his first budget negotiation,” which is followed by the following paragraph:

“Democrats are surprised by just how many concessions they extracted in the trillion-dollar deal, considering that Republicans have unified control of the government. Democratic leaders Charles Schumer and Nancy Pelosi quickly put out celebratory statements last night. Republican leaders Mitch McConnell and Paul Ryan did not. Here are eight ways President Trump **got rolled**.”

Though I don’t find the meanings of “get rolled” in my dictionaries at hand, Urban dictionary defines the meaning of “get rolled” as

1) having been busted by the police or other authority for usually small incidents ie parties. 
The word comes from: the cops "rolled" (in thier cars/motorcycle) up and proceeded to enforce the law.

2) past tense of creating a joint:
We got rolled at the park for smoking our weed that we just rolled.

I also found the following statement online:

For an “older” person the meaning of getting “rolled” is typically understood. However, since my appeal is for all generations to understand and to protect me from being unfairly characterized – I double checked with Urban dictionary. While I discovered a number of more creative definitions, the old school definition seemed to still apply: “getting mugged, ripped off, robbed, etc.” typically coupled with violence. - From ([iontams.com](http://iontams.com/2011/09/16/students-get-rolled-again/)).

To me Urban dictionary’s “busted by the police” doesn’t seem to fit “got rolled” in the “Eight ways Trump got rolled in his first budget negotiation.” It's highly unlikely that the President gets busted. What does this phrase mean in the context of the Washington Post’ s article?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll) gives the sense << **roll** v trans: 7
:  to rob (a drunk, sleeping, or unconscious person) usually by going through the pockets; broadly :  rob >>

Comment: Urban dictionary, while a good source of the existence of slang not found in more formal dictionaries, is not a reliable source of explanations. Somehow most _everything_ tends towards sex there somehow, when it's just not the case usually. (Yes sometimes but not as often as The kids that submit to UD think.

Comment: Search for 'roll a drunk'. I think that usage is more relevant here.

Comment: AHD and RHK Webster's also list this sense, but flag it as 'slang'.

Comment: Either rolled means "got rolled over" or its an alternate misspelling for _t_rolled. Its media speak. I've never known a real person to say someone "got rolled."

Comment: It is old slang and I think it refers to removing a "bankroll" from a drunk while he lies unconcious in a gutter sleeping it off. So in other words, the Dems took him for all he had in the way of concessions that  they extracted in exchange for the vote.

Comment: I'd guess that most young people take it as a combination of the old "mugged" sense and the more recent Sports short hand of 'got rolled over' ... meaning completely dominated and unable to put up any defense against the assault.  I think a figurative use of those same meanings with regards to a police bust is logical for kids who resent that imposition of authority with real consequences for something they regard as routine.

Comment: I don't like that headline. It sounds like Trump ended up negotiating a surprisingly reasonable budget that will please a lot of people, and now the Washington Post is ridiculing him for it. Surely we should spare ridicule for - you know, situations where a politician has done something bad?

Comment: @YoichiOishi, it means simply "was beaten", "was beaten badly".  There are many variations such as "got rolled over".  (That phrase is rather war-like, **specifically from the tank era**: the Germans *rolled over* France in the early years of WW2.)  It's that simple.  If you're asking the ***etymology*** - unknown.  The two senses from urban dictionary are totally unrelated here.

Comment: Re what Mitch mentioned, "urban dictionary" is simply useless.  Not that it's worth addressing, but the claim in "1" ... "this word comes from the cops rolled in cars"  is totally dismissable.  Who knows?  It's a complex etymological question.  Item 2 is just incoherent and means nothing.

Comment: Got rolled is a nicer sound synonym for "got fucked over" here.

Comment: Urban dictionary is not even a good source of slang terminology.  Almost every entry in it is a joke at one level of humor or another.  If it resembles the true meaning in some instance it is only because someone thought it was funnier that way.  I'm always a bit stunned when I see that some people learning English are using it as a source.  In this instance roll is from steamroll, as in RaceYouAnytime's answer.

Answer (score 29):

Especially because this is a headline, it could be a compressed use of the figurative term "**steamrolled**."

On April 25, [*Politico* ran a similar headline](http://www.politico.com/story/2017/04/25/ryan-trump-tax-reform-237604): ***Ryan likely to get rolled on tax reform***.

The content of the article begins:

> Donald Trump is set to **steamroll** Paul Ryan on tax reform, the issue the speaker has devoted his political career to achieving. But don’t expect Ryan to relinquish his pet cause easily.

Unlike the *Politico* piece, the *Washington Post* uses the word "rolled" only in the headline, not in the content, so we can only speculate, but evidently using "rolled" as a condensed form of "steamrolled" has recent precedent.

In this sense, either to "roll" or to "steamroll" means to best an opponent or force them in a particular direction against their will.  See definitions below.

The terms are sometimes used interchangeably in sports reporting as well.  In this recent example, there is no mention of *who* is *getting rolled*, but the use of "roll" in the headline appears to be shorthand for "steamroll" based on the subheading:

> **Headline**: "Bulldogs **roll** their way to Sulphur"
>
> **Subheading**: "Behind their two LSU-Eunice signees, Ascension Catholic was able to dominate Catholic of Pointe Coupee from start to finish and **steamroll** to a 10-1 victory that pushed them through to the semifinals after falling in the quarterfinals for three straight seasons.
>
> - [Donaldsonville Chief, May 3, 2017](http://www.donaldsonvillechief.com/news/20170503/bulldogs-roll-their-way-to-sulphur)

[MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/steamroll) offers this definition of *steamroll*:

> To defeat or destroy an opponent completely.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/189485?rskey=EOUQSx&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid131926474) also offers a figurative definition and example of "steamroll" in this context:

> (b) fig.; (also) to force or drive in a given direction (cf. steam-roller v. 2).
>
> 1975   *Times* 21 July 1/8   The ruling party..will **steamroll** the endorsement through.

It is not uncommon in headline writing to colloquialize or abbreviate expressions to make a concise point, especially in a piece as informal as the *Post* article in question. My interpretation of the headline is that Trump got *steamrolled* by the Democrats.

Comment: This is closer to my understanding of the political term than the lengthy explanation of rick-rolling above...It was interesting but I think overstated the influence of internet memes on political journalism when the idea of steamrolling someone has been around much longer.

Comment: It's totally correct here that the headline means **was beaten badly**.  And it **is true** that the phrase **"steamrolled"** means something like "was beaten badly".  ***BUT*** just to be clear, I really don't think the phrase "rolled" comes from "steamrolled".

Comment: @Fattie I agree that "rolled" can mean many different things, and a lot of them derive from the "swindled" / "cheated" meaning.  But I also think it's in the nature of political writing to use intense action words like "steamrolled," and as in the Politico case, it can be shortened to "rolled."  It's because this is political writing that I interpret it to mean "steamrolled."

Comment: "Steamroll" has the sense of "flatten". I believe this "roll" has the sense of "dislodged"/"sent packing".

Comment: In "steamrolling" it is the advancing party which "rolls". In "getting rolled" it is the retreating party which "rolls" away.

Comment: hey @RaceYouAnytime!  (I will race you anytime, but only over long distances young man!)  Let me just put it this way, where you say ***it could be an abbreviated use of the figurative term***, really, that's not correct.  It is **certainly similar** but it is, quite simply, not derived from and not an abbreviation.  (Note Colin's comment just above mine, which is true.)  FWIW, I'd change your first sentence to:  "Especially because this is a headline, it means dislodged, sent packing, completely beaten; it's rather like the term steamrolled which you also see in politics.".  No biggie, cheers

Comment: @Fattie RE *It could be an abbreviated use of the figurative term*. It certainly could be, because that's exactly what was done in the Politico article.  Just look at the headline and the first sentence.  http://www.politico.com/story/2017/04/25/ryan-trump-tax-reform-237604

Comment: I'm sorry man, they're just different.  In the other article you link, it's just someone using the two different idioms.  Anyway you rock, cheers!

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime good point. It is clear from the politico piece that "got rolled" is sometimes intended as an abbreviation for "got steamrolled". I do not think that is always or even typically the case, however.

Answer (score 27):

*Roll* is one of those words with dozens of different dictionary definitions, plus dozens more slang and metaphorical uses, so I sympathize with you here.

Here, to *roll* someone is to *rob* or to *scam* them, as Cascabel has noted. But furthermore, this usage has become conflated with a type of Internet prank known as *rolling*, with a separate origin, but one that also carries a sense of trickery.

[In Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roll), see verb meaning 24 of *roll*:

> *(transitive) informal, mainly US and New Zealand*
>   to rob (a helpless person, such as someone drunk or asleep)

The archetypical *roll* in American English is to *roll a drunk*; imagine a drunkard passed out on the floor, and turning the body over to steal his wallet or jewelry. One who preys on drunks is thus a *drunk-roller* or *[jack-roller](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jackroller)*, the latter term originating with thieves and prostitutes who targeted lumberjacks, who got paid in a lump sum at the end of the season, and would be flush with cash and whiskey.

Metaphorically, if someone *gets rolled* in a negotiation, they have been swindled or cheated; they are so incompetent or hapless that they might as well have been asleep.

In Internet culture, *[duckrolling](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/duckroll)* began on the 4chan discussion forum around 2006. It began as a joke where *egg* was replaced with *duck* on the board, resulting in the word *eggroll* being replaced with *duckroll*, prompting someone to post an image of a duck with wheels, prompting someone else to create a video clip of this duck with its wheels spinning, prompting still others to advertise one video but link to this one instead.

This gave rise to the much better-known prank of *[rickrolling](http://mashable.com/2017/04/01/history-of-rickroll-meme/)*. Instead of the rolling duck, the surprise clip in a rickroll is the music video of Rick Astley's 1987 song *Never Gonna Give You Up*

As such, *rolling* in Internet slang refers to trickery where one thing is advertised but something else entirely is provided, not unlike a *[bait-and-switch](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bait-and-switch)* scam in commerce. If someone is *rolled*, he or she has fallen prey to the trick.

In the column, Hohmann points out that Congressional Democrats were able to force the administration to make many concessions, even though both houses as well as the White House are controlled by the Republicans. He attributes this to the inexperience of the Trump administration, whose lack of understanding of the rules seems to have allowed them to be *rolled*, whichever way you interpret it.

Comment: good answer... the "rickrolling" definitely captures the commonly understood idea of "being rolled" today in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not still clear. Does "Trump got rolled" mean "Trump is overwhelmed / knocked out flat" or "Trump is cheated / swindled" by Democat's tactics,  while the Washington Post says "the 217-213 vote represented a significant if incomplete political victory for President Trump"? What is the exact alternative word for "got rolled" here?

Comment: I don't think this is the same "get rolled" as the OP is asking about. See my answer below.

Comment: "Here, to roll someone is to rob or to scam them" **totally wrong**.  the headline very simply means nothing more than "was beaten" or "was beaten badly" ir, quite simply, "was forced to roll over" - "was forced in to submission".  Exactly as in "Alabama rolled over the other teams".  (Roll tide!)  There's utterly no connection here to robbing or scamming.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger, Fattie, I disagree, but you are of course free to downvote.

Comment: hi @YoichiOishi - definitely **the former**.  "Trump is overwhelmed", it's that simple.  There is utterly no connection, in any way, to "cheated / swindled".  Note secondly that the "street" sense of "rolled" (we rolled over a drunk and easily took the money from his pockets") has utterly no connection to "cheated / swindled".  It's just the same as saying "completely overwhelmed in a physical battle" and has utterly no connection to "cheated / swindled".

Comment: hi @choster.  I'm afraid you're totally wrong  :)  In your sentence here: * "if someone gets rolled ... they have been A.. swindled or cheated; they are so B...  incompetent or hapless that they might as well have been asleep."*  "A" is completely wrong and unrelated.   "B" is totally correct.  If some toughs "roll" a drunk, it's because the drunk is hapless: (indeed, the drunk person is *so* hapless that  the last thing they would have to do is cheat or swindle ... they just roll them over and help themselves to the money.)

Comment: Quite simply, there is ***utterly no connection*** to cheating or swindling in the article.  On the contrary, the Democrats just simply, well, *rolled* the president: they didn't have to lie, swindle, or make any extreme acts.  It's as simple as saying *"the president caved-in"*.  They rolled that dude!  :)

Comment: for anyone reading this answer, while the explanation of "rickrolling" (the internet slang) is utterly astute and beautifully written (as with every post from Chos) it honestly just has utterly no connection, in any way, at all, whatsoever, not even vaguely or in passing, to the question at hand. (heh!)  to mention that someone was "rolled" in sports or politics is an **utterly everyday phrase**, with an utterly clear meaning ("beaten badly"); other obscure usages ("smoked marijuana!" "internet advertising") are, really, utterly unrelated.

Comment: I am 100% sure the headline is not referring to rickrolling or any other kind of internet troll activity.

Comment: @Fattie did you read the last line in Choster's answer? He admits there are many different interpretations of *rolled* but ultimately the administration *.... whose lack of understanding of the rules seems to have* ***allowed them to be rolled, whichever way you interpret it.*** And that  is utterly, and totally, relevant.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger's answer is correct, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning is given by the 1961 [Books and Bookmen](https://books.google.com/books?id=GKJEAQAAIAAJ&q=%22got%20rolled%22%20robbed&dq=%22got%20rolled%22%20robbed&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI1fe_mdnTAhUJLyYKHetQBWkQ6AEIJzAB)

> But then I finally got rolled (i.e., attacked and robbed).

A more-famous use of the phrase is discussed in the 15 April 1950 article [Is He a Big Laugh!](http://www.unz.org/Pub/Colliers-1950apr15-00022)

> Richard Red Skelton has been specializing in laughter.
>   He will do anything, absolutely anything clean
>   on the screen, stage, radio or in real life to make
>   people laugh, smile, grin, titter, chuckle or giggle.
>   In 1937, for example, when he was working the
>   Capitol Theatre in Washington, D.C., he was invited
>   by President Roosevelt to entertain at a White
>   House luncheon. Midway during the proceedings.
>   Red stopped a Presidential toast by grabbing
>   F.D.R.'s glass. "Careful what you drink, Mr.
>   President," he warned. "I **got rolled** in a place like
>   this once." Roosevelt roared and for years thereafter
>   asked Skelton to emcee the annual Presidential
>   Birthday Ball, the honor the comedian is most
>   proud of.

Comment: This is the interpretation I took from the headline originally: that Trump was metaphorically mugged and had his valuables stolen. The other answers make a good case that the author's intention was otherwise; it may be that "get rolled" has evolved to a more generic meaning from its more violent roots.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham "when the nice new president [Obama] came and offered her [Hillary Clinton] the secretary of state job, and she said yes, she got rolled. What he got was clear: He took her off the chessboard" https://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/07/17/morning-skim-clintons-role-a-message-to-the-naacp-and-more/?_r=0

Answer (score 2):

This "got rolled" is "was forced to back down or depart, was dislodged" (as if  an inanimate obstacle). If you got rolled, probably you have been bested easily, put up little fight.

This meaning is fairly recent slang and appears on [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%28get%29%20rolled), e.g.:

> Rolled - 1. a homeless person rousted from his or her (presumabley illegal) sleeping place by the police "Man, if i sleep in my car, i hope i don't GET ROLLED .

The headline is saying that Trump was handily forced to retreat from his negotiating position.

Answer (score 0):

I've also heard "rolled over" in the same way as "turned over" or possibly "tumbled", all meaning robbed.

Answer (score -1):

"Rolled" looks like the french word "roulé" meaning scammed, swindled

Answer (score -1):

"Rolled" in this sense is referring to a practice is Congress (and other places) called "log-rolling", where favors are traded for things that one party values but the other may not so much, in exchange for the reverse situation. Of course, the way it's written in this piece, it really means (or looks like it means) Trump got taken advantage of in some way.

So yeah, Democrats would be surprised that Trump would not value other Republican policies over those of the Democrats, considering the power imbalance situation, and that Republicans would expect Trump to support their agenda, and not the Democrats' agenda. And in the sport of log-rolling, he would have been rolled right off his log for giving up something so valuable to his opponents so easily.